# How to show Popup view in fullscreen over tabbar and navigationbar in viewcontroller?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I want to show a popup view in my app in full screen, This screen contains tabbar and navigation bar both,  i am getting the problem is when popup shows, it display only in middle of the screen, but  I want to show in fullscreen and above on tabbar and navigationbar, If any person have any idea please provide yout thoughts and solution.I am attaching screenshot of my problem, plz give some solution.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 self.container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
 [self.container addSubview:self.alertView];
 [self.window addSubview:self.container];
```